# Text file sent to Spark worker looks empty or not found

Tags: python, apache-spark, configobj

I want to send a basic config file to every Spark worker. Config file is written for Python's configobj. I specify it while submitting job.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --files .../config.cfg .../spark_str_hello.py
```

But when I try to read it, turns out that it doesn't exist there. When I try print config.sections (which should return a list), empty list is printed. Below is basic example for wordcount. I also tried to initialize config on workers with foreachRDD, had the same result. Is there any special way to send text files to Spark workers?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from configobj import ConfigObj

config = ConfigObj('config.cfg')


sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))
pairs = lines.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
wordCount = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
print config.sections

pairs.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SparkFiles.get("FILE")` to access the files sent via `--files`

Comment: Thank you! I also found out that files can be added via sc.addFile in driver program.